# Why python requests module is not used for web automation testing instead of flaky UI tests?

Tags: python, selenium, automated-tests, ui-automation

I have been automating web application test cases using selenium webdriver most of the time these UI tests
are flaky and brittle but when I use python requests module and I am able to automate reliable test cases with just
GET, POST, DELETE http methods (with help of regular expressions to catch some tokens and ids.) 
My question is that why nobody seems to use http libraries like python requests module to automate web application test cases instead of flaky UI test cases?

Comment: We do use http libs for api testing

Answer (score 4):

You are comparing apples to oranges. You can't use `requests` to test the same things that Selenium can test.

Selenium lets you test the result of rendering HTML and Javascript. `requests` is only a HTTP library, it can make HTTP requests, *and no more*. The tools are different and test different things.

Use `requests` if all you need to do is test if your server is producing the right responses to HTTP requests, like for a REST API. Use Selenium if you need to test how the HTML and Javascript is executed in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about using GET and POST methods directly with the server. Yes they are helpful. Here is my prediction why people wont use it. Because it is  tiresome to do so.
If your application has exposed APIs, its easy to use any API client and contact the server. In your case, I assume there are no exposed APIs and your are intercepting the HTTP traffic to the server to play around with the requests/responses and then use it in your python script. 
The advantage, its Fast and gets the thing done. Disadvantage there is no UI interaction, you wont get the screenshots etc. (like you do when you use selenium ) + you need send a lot of time in hacking around intercepting the HTTP traffic.
Its just a matter of your requirements and time you have in hand.

Comment: Can you provide a valuable link to improve your answer